# Resource Caching in sencha development

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I am using development version of sencha which included microloader --> development.js. I have mentioned **disableCaching:false** inside loader. Still its not cache the resource and duplicate the resource (images,index.html too) when i switch between navigation views.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporarily enable caching in Ext or Touch development, add `?cache` param to the url. For example, `http://localhost/?cache`